# Using Powershell create folder and place file according describe below condition

Tags: powershell

I have many pdf,png files there name are like as below

I have folder named as 1.a chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report.png,1.b chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report.png,2.a chemistry_sem1-answer_technical_report.pdf ,2.b chemistry_sem1-answer_technical_report.pdf and result_sem1-allanswer_technical.pdf I need folder as chemistry(main folder) then after split you get another folder "sem1-questions" then you have file above .

So if you had these file output should be

path of the file =chemistry/sem1-questions/chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report/1.b chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report.png

path of the file =chemistry/sem1-questions/chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report/1.a chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report.png

path of the file=chemistry/sem1-answer/chemistry_sem1-answer/2.a chemistry_sem1-a_technical_report.pdf

Path of the file=result/sem1-allanswer/result_sem1-allanswer_technical.pdf
Thanks

Comment: Show your code and any errors. Stackoverflow is not a scriptwriting service, as many will tell you here, and they would point you to: 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask'. Yet, this is simple file and folder management, and PowerShell 100 level stuff. With examples in the built-in help files and all over the web. Just as in DOS/cmd.exe, create the folder as you would do normally, and use a string match with a directory scan to move the files you'd want using a loop. Youtube is your friend. Just search for 'PowerShell file adn folder management'.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in the directory with all of the chemistry files you listed:

```
New-Item '.\chemistry' -ItemType Directory
New-Item '.\chemistry\sem1-questions' -ItemType Directory
New-Item '.\chemistry\sem1-questions\chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report' -ItemType Directory
New-Item '.\chemistry\sem1-answer' -ItemType Directory
New-Item '.\chemistry\sem1-answer\chemistry_sem1-answer' -ItemType Directory
New-Item '.\chemistry\sem1-allanswer' -ItemType Directory

Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {

    if($_.Name -like "*sem1-questions*") {

        Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination '.\chemistry\sem1-questions\chemistry_sem1-questions_technical_report'

    } elseif ($_.Name -like "*sem1-answer*") {

        Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination '.\chemistry\sem1-answer\chemistry_sem1-answer'

    } elseif ($_.Name -like "*allanswer*") {

        Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination '.\chemistry\sem1-allanswer'

    }

}
```